# Red5pro libred5pro-crypto-5.2.4.so | Red5pro Setup Error

Tags: server, red5pro

I just installed **red5pro 8.1.0** trial license version on my **ubuntu 20 LTS** locally.
There's this error about the a lib called libcrypto. I can't seem to find an solution for that. This is just a new installation.
I am using
**javasdk 1.8**
and I have met every server requirement needed. Please help.

```
[INFO] [pool-5-thread-2] com.red5pro.crypto.CryptoLoader - Storing library path for forced loading: /home/doctor/red5pro-server/lib/amd64-Linux-gpp/jni/libred5pro-crypto-5.2.4.so
[WARN] [pool-5-thread-2] com.red5pro.webrtc.plugin.WebRTCPlugin - Exception loading crypto
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/doctor/red5pro-server/lib/amd64-Linux-gpp/jni/libred5pro-crypto-5.2.4.so: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1088)
    at com.red5pro.crypto.CryptoLoader.loadLibrary(CryptoLoader.java:141)
    at com.red5pro.webrtc.plugin.WebRTCPlugin.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.red5pro.webrtc.plugin.WebRTCPlugin.doStartProPlugin(Unknown Source)
    at com.red5pro.activation.ProPluginator.a(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error when Installed red5pro. Got mad on it and finally found the solution. here it is:

Because of different libcrypto library versions supported between CentOS and Ubuntu, it is necessary to modify {red5pro}/conf/webrtc-plugin.properties, and change openssl.enabled=true to openssl.enabled=false.